# the search view in the action bar move to left when I click on it

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I put search view in the action bar using

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="search"

        />
</menu>
```

and when I click on it it move from the right of action bar to the left , how can I make it stay in the right of action bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just remove this **collapseActionView**

to be like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="search"

    />
```